# $.ajax request always 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the [Kippt API](https://kippt.com/developers/) with $.ajax.

When I use

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Kippt-Username:graph1ZzLle" -H "X-Kippt-API-Token:mytoken" https://kippt.com/api/clips/
```

Everything is running fine and I am getting the JSON response.

However, when it comes to use jQuery with this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var username = "graph1ZzLle";
var token = "*******";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://kippt.com/api/clips/?list=all&include_data=list&limit=10",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Kippt-Username', username)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Kippt-API-Token', token)
        },
        success: function(data) {

            for(var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++) {

                var row = $("<tr/>");
                var date = new Date(data.objects[i]["created"] * 1000); //js works in milliseconds

                $("<td/>").text(date.toLocaleDateString()).appendTo(row);
                $("<td/>").text(data.objects[i]["list"]["title"]).appendTo(row);
                $("<td/>").append("<a href=" + data.objects[i]["url"] + " >" + data.objects[i]["title"] + "</a>").appendTo(row);

                if(data.objects[i]["notes"]) {
                    $("<td/>").text(data.objects[i]["notes"]).appendTo(row);
                } else {
                    $("<td/>").text("-----").appendTo(row);
                }

                row.appendTo("#kippt");
            }
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

I am always gettin the 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) error. I am sure I am using the correct username and token. What is going on ?

Comment: you can't set headers with the JSONP dataType. JSONP requests are created by inserting a <script> tag into the document with a src set to the target location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't set headers with the JSONP dataType. JSONP requests are created by inserting a `<script>` tag into the document with a src set to the target location, and since you can't pass headers with a  tag, your header settings are ignored.

Either use CORS and JSON, or a server-side proxy that gets the data for you.

Comment: well, I will try using the classic XMLHttpRequest object